# Sharepoint list view - set permissions so only certain users can access certain views

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-online, powerapps, sharepoint-list

so I have a sharepoint list that contains all the data (We will call it MasterList), and it has an a dropdown column where different departments can be selected (example Sales, HR, Accounting etc etc). I created a view, which only shows data where HR is selected in this dropdown. Now is it possible to set permissions where a user can only see the HR view, and not the Master list. Basically I only want people from HR to see the HR view, and people from Accounting to only see the Accounting view, and then Admin can see all the views including the master list. Is this possible? Is there a better way to go about this? thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is a way to restrict PowerApps users to a certain Sharepoint List View. Depending on your org's size, you *could* investigate the [Office 365 Users](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-apps/maker/canvas-apps/connections/connection-office365-users) connector in PowerApps. This would allow you to filter the Sharepoint by Department or Job Title.

**Example:** Assumes the Sharepoint list has a column named `dept`

`OnStart` of the app:

```
// Set a variable for the user's department

Set(varUserDept, Office365Users.UserProfileV2(User().Email).department);

// Create a collection from the sharepoint list, filtered by department

ClearCollect(colData,
    Filter(SHAREPOINT_LIST,
        dept = varUserDept
    )
)
```

That being said, if the URL of the Sharepoint list "leaks" users will be able to access the data. [See this forum post](https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/Building-Power-Apps/Powerapps-and-Sharepoint-Online-Permissions/m-p/850520/highlight/true#M270338) for strategies for addressing this issue.